# Core Location, is it possible to supply GPS/Location date to an iPad without the GPS chip for use within the CLLocationManager class?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager

I know there is the core location sim project, however that requires new headers and your app to use them to override the builtin Core Location classes, but is there a way for an app to supply location information to the iDevice (iPhone, iPod, iPad etc) so that apps you installed may get the location information from them?

ie I have written an app to listen to another GPS device, get location information and I wish to supply that data to other apps on my iPad that rely on the standard CoreLocation interface....  Can anyone point to any docs available?  (I don't want to use anything that Apple will block because it's based on hidden/undocumented APIs, nor do I want to rely on something that will require jailbreaking the phone/pad/pod etc.)

Working with iOS 5.1 and above...

Thanks in advance,

Michelle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to override the installed Core Location hardware/software stack and supply your own values to all other apps' CLLocation calls.